# Does the PayPal REST API Support Desktop/Installed Apps?

Tags: paypal

I would like to know if the PayPal REST API Support Desktop/Installed Apps?

When I go to create a new application the only two options for Integration type are 'Web' or 'Mobile SDK'.

Answer (score 0):

REST simply uses HTTP methods to access APIs, so it shouldn't matter whether you have a desktop app. As long as your app can make REST API calls and parse the JSON response, you should be able to use the PayPal REST API.

Comment: True but as I mentioned in my comment on the other thread doesn't OAuth make different assumptions and have different flows to remain secure in different environments (e.g. installed apps where it is assumed secrets are not safe).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Integration Type as Web and use any of the .NET SDKs available here to build Windows Desktop Apps.

http://paypal.github.io/#payments-tab-csharp

Let us know if you are looking for Windows 8 version of the SDK (as this is currently under development).

Comment: Thanks - That's good to hear.

I am not an OAuth expert but I believe some APIs have a specific flow for desktop apps as it must be assumed that the keys and secrets cannot be kept secret (e.g. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#installed).

But it sounds like we can go ahead and use Web as you say.

Comment: You are correct in your question and the answer to that is use only your client_id when shipping the product. You will be able to accept payments just with the client_id. Are you building apps for Win 8 or Win 7 or some other environment?

Comment: I am looking to build a desktop (Windows Forms .NET) app for Windows (7, 8, Server etc.). However I am not looking to take payments - actually I just want to be able to read data on invoices, payments etc. which have gone through our account for generating custom reports. Will I be able to do this?